# Stop a function from running on hover of element

Tags: jquery

I have a function called 'pie' which constantly rotates between 5 different images. What I want to do is stop this from automatically switching the images (stopping pie function from running) when an element has been hovered over.

I thought by passing a value set to either true/false would stop this but it still keeps rotating the images.

Any ideas?

```
var start = true;
pie(start);

$('.pie-state').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    start = false;
    pie(start);
});

function pie(start) {
    if (start) {
        $('.pie').hide().eq(0).show();

        var pause = 1500;
        var motion = 0;
        var pie = $('.pie');
        var piecta = $('.pie-state');
        var count = pie.length;
        var i = 0;
        var c = 1;

        setTimeout(transition, pause);

        function transition() {
            pie.eq(i).animate({
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, motion);
            piecta.removeClass('active');
            piecta.eq(c).addClass('active');

            if (++i >= count) {
                i = 0;
            }

            if (++c >= count) {
                c = 0;
            }

            pie.eq(i).animate({
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, motion);

            setTimeout(transition, pause);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

See the following [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lt0oj4f/)

As you can see there are 5 elements on the right which determine which section of the pie chart is displayed (again using 5 different images).

The rotation works fine but what I need to do now is that when you hover over say 'Electricity', the auto rotation needs to stop and this needs to become the active state. When none of the tabs on the right are hovered over the auto rotation needs to continue.

Comment: Could you provide a Jsfiddle of what happens at current?

Comment: Yep just making one now

Comment: @Kieran - I've added this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your function is *much* too complicated.

You want to switch the CSS class `active` from one element to the next in an interval.

Additionally, the function should check whether there is a mouse pointer hovering over the container and not do anything in this case.

You don't need a function that is any more complex than the following:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#graph-wrapper").is(":hover")) return;
    $(".pie-state.active").removeClass("active").next(".pie-state").addClass("active");
    if (!$(".pie-state").is(".active")) $(".pie-state").first().addClass("active");
}, 1500);
```

This is actually simple enough that it almost reads like plain English.

Expand the snippet below to see it working:

```js
setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#graph-wrapper").is(":hover")) return;
    $(".pie-state.active").removeClass("active").next(".pie-state").addClass("active");
    if (!$(".pie-state").is(".active")) $(".pie-state").first().addClass("active");
}, 1500);
```

```css
.col-md-6, .col-md-5 {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
#carbon-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 694px;
  height: 453px;
  display: block;
}
.pie span {
  width: 333px;
  height: 335px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 60px 0;
}
.pie-state span {
  width: 312px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

#graph-electricity {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-1.png);
}
#graph-agriculture {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-2.png);
}
#graph-residential {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-3.png);
}
#graph-industry {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-4.png);
}
#graph-transportation {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-5.png);
}
#graph-electricity-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-default-1.png);
}
#graph-agriculture-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-default-2.png);
}
#graph-residential-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-default-3.png);
}
#graph-industry-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-default-4.png);
}
#graph-transportation-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-default-5.png);
}
.active #graph-electricity-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-hover-1.png);
}
.active #graph-agriculture-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-hover-2.png);
}
.active #graph-residential-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-hover-3.png);
}
.active #graph-industry-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-hover-4.png);
}
.active #graph-transportation-cta {
  background-image: url(http://alltech.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alltech/assets/img/pie-hover-5.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="graph-wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="pie">
      <span id="graph-electricity"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie">
      <span id="graph-agriculture"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie">
      <span id="graph-residential"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie">
      <span id="graph-industry"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie">
      <span id="graph-transportation"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
    <div class="pie-state active">
      <span id="graph-electricity-cta"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie-state">
      <span id="graph-agriculture-cta"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie-state">
      <span id="graph-residential-cta"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie-state">
      <span id="graph-industry-cta"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pie-state">
      <span id="graph-transportation-cta"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please, for the OCDs, could you add some hover handling? (I mean something like `$('.pie-state').hover(function() { $('.pie-state.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); });`), otherwise hovering makes a freeze effect that seems odd

Comment: @arhak Well, mine was meant to be a minimal solution. It's reasonable to add niceties like this and the OP can do so at their discretion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the timeout inside the transition method. and also assign global variable for the setimeout in pie method.
timer = setTimeout(transition, pause);(timer should be decalred in the top of the document)

on hover event - clearTimeOut(timer)

on mouse leave event = again do timer = setTimeout(transition, pause);